# Error 438 (Doesn't Support this method... ) When the method is valid?

Tags: vba, ms-access

Okay, So I have a collection :
Making some clarifications :
At the top of a module that controls the reports: ConReps

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public cCenter As New colCenters
Public colCenters As New Collection
```

I load the collection as needed from a series of buttons on a form:

```
Private Sub tgl_100_Click()

If tgl_100 = 0 Then
    Dec (rIterator)
    colCenters.Remove "100"
    Exit Sub
Else
    Inc (rIterator)
    Call XXXFilter("100")
End If

If Me.tgl_All = -1 Then Me.tgl_All = 0

End Sub
```

Long and short, this will be used to filter a report, there are up to 32 total options, with no forewarning as to what the choices will be. As such, I chose to use toggle buttons with some simple code to load up the collection for later use in a filter WHERE statement.

The collection is loaded in XXXFilter which is in ConReps

```
Public Sub XXXFilter(Filter As String)

Dim i As Integer

If rIterator = 1 Then Set colCenters = New Collection
If rIterator = 1 Then Set cCenter = New colCenters

If Filter = "remove" And rIterator > 0 Then
    GoTo resetSQL
ElseIf Filter = "remove" And rIterator = 0 Then
    pFSQL = ""
    Exit Sub
End If

With cCenter
    .CallCenter = Filter
    colCenters.Add cCenter, Key:=Filter
    'Debug.Print colCenters.count
End With

Exit Sub

resetSQL:

    pFSQL = " WHERE Site1 LIKE *" & cCenter(1) & "*"
    For i = 1 To rIterator
        pFSQL = pFSQL & " OR Site1 LIKE *" & colCenters(i) & "*"
    Next i

End Sub
```

The information from the Class module, colCenters, is here:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Option Base 1
Private c_Loc As String

Property Get CallCenter() As String
    
    CallCenter = c_Loc

End Property

Property Let CallCenter(L As String)

    c_Loc = L

End Property

Public Function rfSQL()

Dim i As Integer

If rIterator = 1 Then
    pFSQL = " WHERE Site1 LIKE *" & cCenter(1) & "*"
ElseIf rIterator <> 0 Then
    pFSQL = " WHERE Site1 LIKE *" & cCenter(1) & "*"
    For i = 1 To rIterator
        pFSQL = pFSQL & " OR Site1 LIKE *" & colCenters(i) & "*"
    Next i
Else
    MsgBox "An Error in Class Module colCenters" & vbCrLf & " has occurred code : rfSQL ", vbOKOnly, "colCenters Error"
End If

Debug.Print pFSQL

End Function
```

So the heart of the issue I am having is this:

Valid properties for a Collection : Add, Remove, Count, Item
I can Add, I can Remove, I can Count. But the .Item fails every time throwing out a 438 error "Object Doesn't support this property or method"

I assume something, somewhere in my code is why it's throwing this error, but I can't figure it out. Do any of you see anything that could explain it?

it was mentioned that the call to the collection, from a different command button in the form that holds tgl_100:

```
Sub cmd_OpenReport
...

If rIterator = 1 Then
    pFSQL = " WHERE Site1 LIKE *" & cCenter(1) & "*"
ElseIf rIterator <> 0 Then
    pFSQL = " WHERE Site1 LIKE *" & cCenter(1) & "*"
    For i = 1 To rIterator
        pFSQL = pFSQL & " OR Site1 LIKE *" & colCenters(i) & "*"
    Next i
Else
    MsgBox "An Error in Class Module colCenters" & vbCrLf & " has occurred code : S_OQERO ", vbOKOnly, "Switchboard Error"
End If

...
End Sub
```

pFSQL is a public string variable.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code where `collection.item` is used

Comment: .Item is the default call for a collection, While I didn't link the code that initializes rfSQL it looks identical to what you see in the above segment.

Comment: It may be because you have a collection with the same name as your class module, or because your class has no default property so it doesn't know how to concatenate an object into a string.

Comment: I will check on those and see if that is it, I have done collections with class names in the past, but I have run out of ideas, I 'll let you know if it works.

Comment: We have no idea what your secret `colCenters` is. To add to the confusion, you reuse that name for a new Collection ... so no one here can compile your code.

Comment: colCenters was the class object that I posted above. The error is almost certainly in that code, I have been experimenting for a bit and narrowed that much down.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this...

```
Public cCenter As New colCenters
Public colCenters As New Collection
```

..doesn't even compile.

That said,

> I assume something, somewhere in my code is why it's throwing this error, but I can't figure it out.

Place a breakpoint (F9) at start first line of code in your procedure. Run it and when VBA stops at the breakpoint, step through it with F8 and locate the line that causes the error.

Comment: The entire thing compiles on my end, I did a step by step, it only breaks at the lines where it is trying to get any information out of the collection via colCenters.Item(i) where i is index. I tried accessing it directly through the immediate window by key and that still didn't work.

Comment: Well, it doesn't compile in VB6 _(that's where I tried it)_ as `colCenters` isn't a `Class` nor any other object VB could create an instance of. And both lines are basically identical to `Public cCenter As New Collection`

Comment: That's weird, after you said that I created a completely new Access DB just to test it, and it still compiled for me. I did narrow down the problem to something in the Class Module, I just am not sure what. I will have to find another solution it appears.

Comment: Thanks for trying that out. TIL: this is a difference between VB6's implementation and the _(newer)_ VBA 7.1. Still my point stands: if you define `colCenters` as a `Collection` and then `cCenter` as `colCenters`, what you actually did is `Public cCenter As New Collection`. I wonder what's the purpose for this?

Comment: In this case it was because I had intended to use the Class Module to create multiple different collections of the same structure, to be used in a couple of cases at the same time, at least that was the intent.